# how can install mkinitrd in ubuntu-14.04

Tags: linux-kernel

```
root@akshit-Vostro-1550:/boot# mkinitrd -o initrd.img-2.6.32 2.6.32
mkinitrd: command not found
apt-get install mkinitrd-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mkinitrd-tools
```

/*initrd images contains device driver which needed to load rest of the operating system later on. Not all computer requires initrd, but it is safe to create one.*/

Answer (score 3):

After a little research I found out that in Ubuntu mkinitramfs command is used instead of mkinitrd.
Refer to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516882/e-unable-to-locate-package-mkinitrd)

Comment: yesterday i also found "mkinitramfs" but how to create img file by using this command

Comment: mkinitramfs -o initrd.img-2.6.32 2.6.32
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_TAuW4p/lib/modules/2.6.32/modules.builtin: No such file or directory               /* can somone solve this problem */